# Can't build the android project

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kapt

I just upgrade kotlin `1.2.71` to `1.3.0-rc-190` and now I can't compile my project. Is the first time I see this error and I haven't found any solution, please help!

The error log:

```
04:11:56.678 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Internal compiler error. See log for more details
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
04:11:56.679 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
```

My app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        /*Config*/

        kapt {
            arguments {
                arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas".toString())
            }
        }

    }
    // buildTypes
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    dataBinding.enabled = true

}
androidExtensions { experimental = true }

dependencies {

    /* My dependencies */

}
```

My android studio version is 3.2.

**Edit**
Full Error Log: [Full Error Log](https://ghostbin.com/paste/qx5a4)

Comment: Can you please attach a full compiler stack trace and steps to reproduce the problem? If possible please create an issue at http://kotl.in/issue and attach your project (can be done privately) so we can diagnose the problem.

Comment: Please also try to disable the light analysis mode: `kapt { useLightAnalysis = false }`.

Comment: Also please try 1.3.0-rc-184 (or older versions) as there's a possibility that changes in 1.3.0-rc-185 may cause this problem.

Comment: Okay, I'll let you know tomorrow, I can't do this today